# Align text to the middle with Chinese text

Tags: html, css

I am having a problem to align text in the same div when the text is in Chinese.
It pushes the right span to the top from some reason.
Is there a way to fix this issue?

```css
.left{
  float:left
}

.right{
  float:right;
}

div{
  clear:both;
  width:400px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span class="left">【夏向け】怖い、こっくりさん【ホラー】</span>
  <span class="right">Android</span>
  </div>
<div>
  <span class="left">Hello world</span>
  <span class="right">Facbook</span>
</div>
<div>
  <span class="left">【夏向け</span>
  <span class="right">Android</span>
  </div>
<div>
  <span class="left">This is an example text</span>
  <span class="right">Android</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the `line-height` and `font-size` property accordingly

```css
.left{
  float:left
}

.right{
  float:right;
}

div{
  clear:both;
  width:400px;
  line-height: 24px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span class="left">【夏向け】怖い、こっくりさん【ホラー】</span>
  <span class="right">Android</span>
  </div>
<div>
  <span class="left">Hello world</span>
  <span class="right">Facbook</span>
</div>
<div>
  <span class="left">【夏向け</span>
  <span class="right">Android</span>
  </div>
<div>
  <span class="left">This is an example text</span>
  <span class="right">Android</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`float` is messing up the code

```css
.left{
  display:table-cell;
  text-align:left;
}

.right{
  display:table-cell;
  text-align:right;
}

div{
  display: table;
  width:500px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span class="left">【夏向け】怖い、こっくりさん【ホラー】</span>
  <span class="right">Android</span>
  </div>
<div>
  <span class="left">Hello world</span>
  <span class="right">Facbook</span>
</div>
<div>
  <span class="left">【夏向け</span>
  <span class="right">Android</span>
  </div>
<div>
  <span class="left">This is an example text</span>
  <span class="right">Android</span>
</div>
```